# can i use html with the MERN stack?

Tags: html, mern

hi I'm completely new to the MERN stack and am completely comfortable with html and CSS. however when I look at MERN tutorials online I see no html. is there a way I can still write up my websites I want to create using html and CSS then dealing with back end using MERN?

Answer (score 1):

The "R" in MERN stands for React, which means writing JavaScript (or TypeScript) using the React ecosystem, usually including JSX (which is an XML/HTML-like syntax for representing UI) React is what you'd use instead of writing HTML and vanilla JS or jQuery. Anything you can do with React, you can do with plain HTML, CSS, and JS, though it might take a lot more work. If you use Mongo, Express, and Node, without React, that would work perfectly fine, but it wouldn't be the MERN stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your normal HTML CSS & JAVASCRIPT for the frontend.
But before that lets understand what is **MERN**.

MERN --> stands from MongoDB , Express , React , Node js

Let's breakdown more:-

Mongo DB --> This is a database

Express --> This is a package to make our server (just like http package)

React --> This is a frontend framework for creating React apps.

Node js-->This is the environment for running your javascript code (Basically your javascript code runs on a browser environment but when you deploy your javascript codes on the server for making the backend there is no browser that's why we use node to provide a javascript environment to run the javascript files )

Collectively we make a whole website using all these.
But as you said can we use HTML , Yes you can use HTML to make your frontend only but you can't use HTML to program your backend because it's not possible.

In MERN you can replace "R" With (HTML , CSS , JAVASCRIPT) But MEN will be going to remain the same because these are used only to make your backend.

And combining it all We call FullStack web development.

I hope you will get it all. :)